# playing video in iOS 5

Tags: ios5, video

I am trying to follow this tutorial [link](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Video_Playback_from_within_an_iOS_5_iPhone_Application), but i have issues. Can somebody please have a look and let me know what needs to be changed. 
I tried to looking up other examples but none seems to work. Please let me know what needs to be changed.

The following is the error

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in VideoScreenViewController.o
  "_MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification", referenced from:
      -[VideoScreenViewController playVideo:] in VideoScreenViewController.o
      -[VideoScreenViewController moviePlayBackDidFinish:] in VideoScreenViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is the code

```
//  VideoScreenViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"
@interface VideoScreenViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender;

@end

    }


#import "VideoScreenViewController.h"
#import "MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h"
@interface VideoScreenViewController ()

@end

@implementation VideoScreenViewController

@synthesize moviePlayer;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                             pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"MOV"]];
        moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL:url];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:moviePlayer];

        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];


}


- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                         pathForResource:@"Movie" ofType:@"MOV"]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    if ([player
         respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [player.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: your answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464347/iphone-sdk-4-weird-compilation-error-mpmovieplayercontroller

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add MediaPlayer.framework to your project..and then try..

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem today and i found out that the media player framework has to be added correctly: so at first right click on "frameworks" click on "add files to.."
located the framework within the folder "developers/Platforms....etpp" then click on "create folder references for any added folders" and click "add" finally - thats it. After this the error did not appear anymore.